# Need to split file name into two parts using python

Tags: python, split

I'm new to python and i am  trying to split the filenames that i have read from a directory. I could split the file names from the extension but splitting the name is what i want. Here is my code...can you help me on how to do this. I want to split error log and December with the date( i.e into two parts with error in one and date time into 2nd part.

```
import os
import os.path
path = 'C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\xls'
text_files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(path)]
print (text_files)
r = str(text_files)
f = "C:\\Users\\abc\\xls"
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
f.write(r)
f.close()
```

The exact names of files in the directory are :

1. Error_Log_December_10_2016_06_19_05 PM.txt
2. Error_Log_December_15_2016_06_19_05 PM.txt

   around 50 files are present like this which are to be split. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by splitting the name? What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Forget about everything else. You just want to split a string in a particular way, the rest is a distraction. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I want the file to be like this -- Error_Log & December_10_2016_06_19_05 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already know how to remove the extension.

```
v = 'Error_Log_December_15_2016_06_19_05 PM'

a = v.split('_')

errLog = '_'.join(a[0:2])

dateString = '_'.join(a[2:])
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Its because you are not printing the variable, you have no output.

Comment: No, it says ----- 'list' object has no attribute 'split'!!

Comment: The above code first splits the string with `_` and then a list is created. This list is then joined such that you can get the desired two parts of that string. It should work @AkhilKodicherla

Answer (score 0):

To split the file name between `Error_Log` and `December_...` you might want to look at [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 0):

If the name always start with `Error_Log` you simply silice it like an array of characters.

```
v = "Error_Log_December_10_2016_06_19_05 PM.txt"
print v[0:9]
print v[10:]
```